# Minecraft PE horses attracted to certain places?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a herd of about 20 untamed horses in a very large fenced area in Minecraft PE. They have grass and shelter in the area but they seem to be attracted to one corner of the area. I move them to the other side with hay and wheat but after about 5 mins, half of them are back in the corner. Anyone ever heard of this before?

Comment: Horses wander randomly - this means they pick a random destination and pathfind to it. What you are observing may be either due to pathfinder deeming some specific area more preferable to pass through than others (though horses can't leave anyway), or some glitch with coordinate signs (like horses being more prone to navigate to positive coordinates than negative, or vice versa).

Comment: Can you check with F3 debug screen which corner horses go to? Check X and Z coordinates of a "preferred corner", and also of an "avoided corner".

Answer (score -1):

This situation seems familiar to me even with other animals. However, there may be a reason for this. First, check if there is anything on the other side that may be scaring them (though I dont know what scares horses in the first place.) Secondly, you may want to make sure there is not any place to escape from  that they are trying to approach. 
Thats what I could think of, or it might just be normal. Hope that could kinda help!

Comment: Horses are not scared of anything, including a murder-bent player, in Minecraft.